# DisplayFor in list using foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    var cor_pay_schedules = db.COR_PAY_SCHEDULES.Where(x=> x.PAY_SCHEDULE_GROUP_ID == id).ToList();
    if (cor_pay_schedules == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(cor_pay_schedules);
}
```

And, view:

```
@model IEnumerable<PartnerShips.COR_PAY_SCHEDULES>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>TMP_UNI_PAY_SCHEDULES</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @foreach (var q in Model)
        {

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => q.BEGIN_DATE)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.BEGIN_DATE)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => q.END_DATE)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.END_DATE)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => q.AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => q.AMOUNT_PERCENTAGE)
            </dd>

        }
    </dl>
</div>
```

In `q` it retrieves list correctly, but it throws an exception:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor,System.DateTime>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.DateTime>>)'

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your Model (COR_PAY_SCHEDULES) too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change

```
@model IEnumerable<PartnerShips.COR_PAY_SCHEDULES>
```

to

```
@model List<PartnerShips.COR_PAY_SCHEDULES>
```

Comment: Because you called `.ToList()` and your view expects `IEnumerable` ,you have two solutions:
1) Change the code on view to use `List`
2) Remove `.ToList()` from your code in controller

Answer (score 0):

Basically George what happened is Ienumerable does not like when you try to 
display the attribute name of an actual instance of it's model.

It will want you to display it directly from model instead such as:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.END_DATE)
```

instead of displaying the name from the instance

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => q.END_DATE)
```

I think that's the more "correct" way to do it.

The point is the name of the field will not change over iteration so it seems 
rather illogical to display it from an iterated variable.

Edit: Ienumerable CAN receive the .ToList() it's basically just a list that supports a simple iteration.